# Why Masashi Kishimoto did not author Boruto?

Tags: naruto, boruto

I mean he successfully completed **Naruto**, so why not continue it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He needed a break!

[An excerpt from an interview he did at New York Comic Con (per Anime News Network)](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/interview/2015-10-14/masashi-kishimoto-at-new-york-comic-con/.94188):

> **Christopher Butcher:
>   *72 volumes of Naruto. Did the editors of Shonen Jump want you to keep going? Some of the Shonen Jump series go for a hundred volumes or two
>   hundred volumes. Did the editors want you to keep going on Naruto?***
>
> **Masashi Kishimoto:** I would be lying if I said there wasn't some pressure from management, the powers that be as they were, but I had a
>   pretty clear idea of how I wanted the story to come to a close, so I
>   had to put my foot down and say, 'No, I'm sorry, this is it.'

It's also the case that during the creation of *Naruto*, Kishimoto got married and was supposed to go on his honeymoon with his wife, but never did.  After the series was completed, [he was finally able to do that](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-07-28/naruto-creator-on-being-asked-for-sequel-please-let-me-rest-now/.90993), even though his son was (at the time) about as old as Boruto would be in-canon.

Comment: if people only knew how amazing a feat of endurance and hard work authoring a shonen manga for 15 years truly is, they would not begrudge him a holiday.